# requests.get() raises SSL Error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am using Python 2.7.3 on a shared FreeBSD host.
The installed version of python requests module is 2.11.1.

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
s = requests.Session()
s.server = "dns-api.company.net"
s.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
s.headers = {'User-Agent':'DNS-Client'}
s.verify = False
r = s.get('https://dns-api.company.net/query') //Not the actual url
```

As you can see I am setting `verify` to False. Yet I get the following SSL error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno bad handshake] [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', '')]
```

I have tried the following variations but to no avail as I end up with the same error.

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

r = requests.get("https://dns-api.company.net/query", verify=False, auth=('user','pass')) // Dummy URL
```

I don't care about SSL verification. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you don't care about ssl verification, why do you use https?

Comment: If I use http instead of https I get the following error-
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'hostname nor servname provided, or not known'))`

Comment: I opened the url in a browser, and the ssl is improperly configured on their side. The certificate you receive is valid only for `cc.sedoparking.com`. Contact them to see if it can be fixed.

Comment: Haha. That's not the actual URL. 'dns-api' has a real DNS server name and 'company' has company name both of which I'd rather not mention. And 'query' is the zonefile query.

Comment: there are many cases where questions are asked with actual urls in the question. please make it explicit in the question